# C HTTP streaming server to stream audio decibel levels

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, alsa, decibel

Hi I have written a decibel level meter in C which reads Linux alsa constantly and output decibel levels numbers in STDOUT.

Now I would like to view via HTTP and streaming live data to clients, with proper js+html decoration, it behaves as a noise meter, with graph and needles.

Therefore I would like to know if some one can point me direction integrate them into a HTTP streaming server able to server multiple clients in real time.

Comment: You could integrate a simple socket server in the program, that accepts connections and simply streams the numbers (as strings) to the connected clients. Then use whatever webapp-framework (be it PHP, Python or anything else) you want to connect to this server and read out the data. Or write the values to a file, and let the webapp read this file at regular intervals.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, I hope could be 1 file solution to minimize delay. and I don't have much exp with socket programming in C. my c coding doing decibel is here: https://raw.github.com/c2h2/csounds-stuff/master/dB_meter_bar.c

Comment: I'm no expert, but you should be able to integrate this into a standard webserver like nginx using CGI. Due to the way JavaScript works, though, you won't be able to see data until the HTTP request is complete. You'll need to balance polling frequency against the resulting latency. (TL;DR: There is no such thing as HTTP streaming with AJAX.)

Comment: Also, please accept more answers to past questions.

Comment: hi I couldn't accept previous answer which was not correct. and normal CGI + webserver wouldn't work, because they are trying to access ALSA where can only be one process to access, therefore a standalone server would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several C libraries. Some C libraries provide HTTP server abilities, e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/). Other libraries provide HTTP client abilities, e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

All are using some event loop, e.g. [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or at least some multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html)

You could also make your application a FASTCGI app.

Reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) should help.